# MySQL cant create an Table PHP Table 'x.y' doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, database

***Closed Anwer found in comments***

I've got an script that should create an Table but it doesn't do it. be for i am edit it, it work and i can't see my mistake but I am not good in php.
 **Code PHP:**

```
$sqlAb = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS clanmember(
count int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
nickname varchar(255),
role varchar(255),
wotid varchar(255),
ts3id varchar(255),
LastOnlineTS3 DATE,
U18 BOOL,
primary key(wotid),
key(count)";
mysql_connect('localhost','root','password');
//mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('wordpress_clan');
mysql_query($sqlAb);
```

and later i want to check if row U18  true is this possible with this?

```
if ($row['U18']==true){$cou .="servergroupaddclient sgid=73 cldbid={$row['ts3id']}\n";}
```

after running the script i got this

> Table 'wordpress_clan.clanmember' doesn't exist

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you try it with this code and provide the error message (if any): `mysql_query($sqlAb) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: If you just created the table in a MySQL client first, you will see why it fails.

Comment: Oh, another problem is that it has no closing `)`.

Comment: Thx it was only i hve forgotto close it